# CS50 pset 4 // sepia filter

Tags: c, cs50

Hello I am having an issue with the sepia filter for my cs50 course this is the error it gives me.I am really not sure what the issue is. If anyone could help me that would be great

[image: I am not sure what to do with this error message and what it means because everything seems to be working correctly but it's giving an error]

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
double sepiaRed;
double sepiaGreen;
double sepiaBlue;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        sepiaRed = (0.393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed) + (0.769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen) + (0.189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
        sepiaGreen = (0.349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed) + (0.686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen) + (0.168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
        sepiaBlue = (0.272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed) + (0.534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen) + (0.131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);


        if( sepiaRed > 255)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
        }

        else if(sepiaGreen > 255)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
        }

        else if(sepiaBlue > 255){
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
        }

        else{
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sepiaRed);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sepiaGreen);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sepiaBlue);
        }

     }
}
return;
```

}

Comment: You should ask this question in the dedicated CS50 StackExchange site https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Floating point arithmetic will almost always lead to compounding rounding errors, possibly leading to wrong results. Try to figure out a way to do the calculations without using floating point arithmetic.

Comment: thank you everyone this also helps my knowledge thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cases where you clamp one component to `255` you have not updated the other components. I suggest changing the faulty logic in this section of the code

```
if( sepiaRed > 255) {
    image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
}
else if(sepiaGreen > 255) {
    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
}
else if(sepiaBlue > 255) {
    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
}
else {
    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sepiaRed);
    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sepiaGreen);
    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sepiaBlue);
}
```

to this, which clamps each component and then writes them all

```
if(sepiaRed > 255) {
    sepiaRed = 255;
}
if(sepiaGreen > 255) {
    sepiaGreen = 255;
}
if(sepiaBlue > 255) {
    sepiaBlue = 255;
}
image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sepiaRed);
image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sepiaGreen);
image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sepiaBlue);
```